# Separating NiCl2 and CoCl2

Tags: solutions

My undergraduate lab is currently doing a project in which we have to separate inorganic compounds from organic compounds, identify each compound, and quantify how much of each compound there is. We've identified that the inorganic compounds are NiCl2 and CoCl2, and quantified them using Beer's Law. However, our project specifications say we need to come up with two ways of quantifying them, and we're stumped on finding a second way. Is there a reaction that can possibly titrate one of the compounds without having the other compound interfere, or perhaps separate them and then weigh them using a gravimetric approach? The problem is that the two compounds seem to have the same solubility properties so we don't quite know how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: Read about atomic absorption spectrophotometry; Also read this classical method....https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac60094a033?src=recsys&journalCode=ancham

Comment: Using dimethylglyoxime (DMG) to precipitate nickle is a classic. At one time the pipe dream was to find reagents that would specific for each element, or a very limited sets of elements.